# How do I perform an "OR" filter on an aggregate?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to grab the first 10 documents grouped by domain. These 10 documents need to have a value for "crawl_date" that haven't been crawled for a while or haven't been crawled at all (eg a blank value). I have:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/tester/test/_search' -d '
{
  "size": 10,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_domain": {
            "filter": {
                "or":[
                        "term": {"crawl_date": ""},
                        "term": {"crawl_date": ""}  // how do I put a range here? e.g. <= '2014-12-31'
                    ]
            },
      "terms": {
        "field": "domain"
      }
    }
  } 
}'
```

I am new to ES and using version 2.2. Since the documentation isn't fully updated I am struggling.

EDIT:
To clarify, I need 10 urls that haven't been crawled or haven't been crawled for a while. Each of those 10 urls has to come from a unique domain so that when I crawl them I don't overload someone's server.

Another Edit:
So, I need something like this (1 link for each of 10 unique domains):

```
1. www.domain1.com/page
2. www.domain2.com/url
etc...
```

Instead, I am getting just the domain and the number of pages:

```
"buckets": [
          {
            "key": "http://www.dailymail.co.uk",
            "doc_count": 212
          },
          {
            "key": "https://sedo.com",
            "doc_count": 196
          },
          {
            "key": "http://www.foxnews.com",
            "doc_count": 118
          },
          {
            "key": "http://data.worldbank.org",
            "doc_count": 117
          },
          {
            "key": "http://detail.1688.com",
            "doc_count": 117
          },
          {
            "key": "https://twitter.com",
            "doc_count": 112
          },
          {
            "key": "http://search.rakuten.co.jp",
            "doc_count": 104
          },
          {
            "key": "https://in.1688.com",
            "doc_count": 92
          },
          {
            "key": "http://www.abc.net.au",
            "doc_count": 87
          },
          {
            "key": "http://sport.lemonde.fr",
            "doc_count": 85
          }
        ]
```

The "hits" returns multiple pages for just 1 domain:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "tester",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/at-the-edge-of-the-orchard-tracy-chevalier/1121908441?ean=9780525953005",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "domain": "http://www.barnesandnoble.com",
          "crawl_date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "tester",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "http://www.barnesandnoble.com/b/bargain-books/_/N-8qb",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "domain": "http://www.barnesandnoble.com",
          "crawl_date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
      },
      etc....
```

Barnes and Noble will quickly ban my UA if I try to crawl that many domains at the same time.

I need something like this:

```
1. "http://www.dailymail.co.uk/page/text.html",
2. "https://sedo.com/another/page"
3. "http://www.barnesandnoble.com/b/bargain-books/_/N-8qb"
4. "http://www.starbucks.com/homepage/"
etc.
```

Comment: That means you are getting  `www.dailymail.co.uk` instead of  `http://www.dailymail.co.uk/page/text.html`. What is the mapping of `domain`. I guess it is an `analyzed` String. That's why your text is getting tokenized.

Comment: domain is "not_analyzed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using Aggregations

If you want to use aggregations, I'd suggest using the terms aggregations to remove the duplicates from your result set and as sub aggregation, I'd use the [top_hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html), which gives you the best hit from the aggregated documents of each domain (per default the score for each document within a domain should be the same.)

Consequently the query will look like that:

```
POST sites/page/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filtered_domains": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "crawl_date"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "crawl_date": {
                  "lte": "2016-01-01"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "domains": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "domain",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "pages": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Giving you results like that

```
"aggregations": {
"filtered_domains": {
  "doc_count": 3,
  "domains": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "barnesandnoble.com",
        "doc_count": 2,
        "pages": {
          "hits": {
            "total": 2,
            "max_score": 1,
            "hits": [
              {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "page",
                "_id": "barnesandnoble.com/test2.html",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                  "crawl_date": "1982-05-16",
                  "domain": "barnesandnoble.com"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "starbucks.com",
        "doc_count": 1,
        "pages": {
          "hits": {
            "total": 1,
            "max_score": 1,
            "hits": [
              {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "page",
                "_id": "starbucks.com/index.html",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                  "crawl_date": "1982-05-16",
                  "domain": "starbucks.com"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Using Parent/Child Aggregations

If you can change your index structure, I'd suggest to create an index with either parent/child relationship or nested documents.

If you do so, you can select 10 distinct domains and retrieve one (or more) specific pages of this url.

Let me show you an example with parent/child (if you use sense, you should be able to just copy paste):

**First generate the mappings for the documents:**

```
PUT /sites 
{
  "mappings": {
    "domain": {},
    "page": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "domain" 
      },
      "properties": {
        "crawl_date": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Insert some documents**

```
PUT sites/domain/barnesandnoble.com
{}
PUT sites/domain/starbucks.com
{}
PUT sites/domain/dailymail.co.uk
{}
POST /sites/page/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": "barnesandnoble.com/test.html", "parent":    "barnesandnoble.com" }}
{ "crawl_date": "1982-05-16" }
{ "index": { "_id": "barnesandnoble.com/test2.html", "parent": "barnesandnoble.com" }}
{ "crawl_date": "1982-05-16" }
{ "index": { "_id": "starbucks.com/index.html", "parent": "starbucks.com" }}
{ "crawl_date": "1982-05-16" }
{ "index": { "_id": "dailymail.co.uk/index.html", "parent": "dailymail.co.uk" }}
{}
```

**Search for the urls to crawl**

```
POST /sites/domain/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "page",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "must_not": {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "crawl_date"
                      }
                    }  
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "crawl_date": {
                      "lte": "2016-01-01"
                    }
                  }     
                }]

            }

          }
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {
        "size": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We do a *has_child* query on the parent type and therefor receive only distinct urls of the parent type. To get the specific pages, we have to add an [inner_hits query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html), which gives us the child documents leading to the hits in the parent type.
If you set inner_hits size to 1, you get only one page per domain. 
You can even add a sorting in the inner_hits query... For example, you can sort by the crawl_date. ;)

The above search gives you the following result:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "sites",
    "_type": "domain",
    "_id": "starbucks.com",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {},
    "inner_hits": {
      "page": {
        "hits": {
          "total": 1,
          "max_score": 1.9664046,
          "hits": [
            {
              "_index": "sites",
              "_type": "page",
              "_id": "starbucks.com/index.html",
              "_score": 1.9664046,
              "_routing": "starbucks.com",
              "_parent": "starbucks.com",
              "_source": {
                "crawl_date": "1982-05-16"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "sites",
    "_type": "domain",
    "_id": "dailymail.co.uk",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {},
    "inner_hits": {
      "page": {
        "hits": {
          "total": 1,
          "max_score": 1.9664046,
          "hits": [
            {
              "_index": "sites",
              "_type": "page",
              "_id": "dailymail.co.uk/index.html",
              "_score": 1.9664046,
              "_routing": "dailymail.co.uk",
              "_parent": "dailymail.co.uk",
              "_source": {}
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "sites",
    "_type": "domain",
    "_id": "barnesandnoble.com",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {},
    "inner_hits": {
      "page": {
        "hits": {
          "total": 2,
          "max_score": 1.4142135,
          "hits": [
            {
              "_index": "sites",
              "_type": "page",
              "_id": "barnesandnoble.com/test.html",
              "_score": 1.4142135,
              "_routing": "barnesandnoble.com",
              "_parent": "barnesandnoble.com",
              "_source": {
                "crawl_date": "1982-05-16"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Finally, let me note one thing. Parent/child relationship comes with small costs at query time. If this isn't a problem for your use case, I'd go for this solution.

Comment: I'm too afraid of the performance hit...this index will potentially have billions of pages ;(

Comment: What are the required response times? From my experience, these queries are slower, however they are still fast enough.

Comment: I added a alternative solution using aggregations

Comment: @kristen does the aggregation using top hits work like you expect it?

Comment: No. It doesn't seem to group by domain correctly and I get more than 1 link for "http://www.engadget.com" as well as other domains.

Comment: Are you sure that your index is correct? E.g. perhaps it is because of http and https? I'd store only the domain in the domain field.

Comment: The http/https is correct. It is fine to return 1 http and 1 https link but I am getting multiple for each.

Comment: Mmh... Can you provide an example of your response? As you see in my response example it did work in my test scenario :/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the [`exists` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) instead of trying to match an empty `term` (the [`missing` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-query.html) is deprecated in 2.2). Then, the [`range` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) will help you filter out the documents you don't need.

Finally, since you have used the absolute URL as id, make sure to aggregate on the `_uid` field and not the domain field, that way you'll get unique counts per exact page.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/tester/test/_search' -d '{
  "size": 10,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_domain": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "crawl_date"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "crawl_date": {
                  "lte": "2014-12-31T00:00:00.000"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "domains": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "_uid"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: You have used 2 aggregation type : `filter` and `terms` in `group_by_domain` . If I am not wrong that is not allowed.  You have to use `sub aggregation` there. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're right, I've blindly copied the initial query and didn't fix the sub-aggregation part. Thanks Richa.

Comment: Sorry, that question was more geared @kristen ;)

Comment: @val am in middle of something else but will test this shortly.

Comment: That's not doing it. Need to group by domain, not the link.

Comment: I don't get it, in your edit you said you needed to know the unique URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Filter Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) and then sub-aggregation

```
{
"size": 10,
"aggs": {
  "filter_date": {
     "filter": {
        "bool": {
           "should": [
              {
                 "bool": {
                    "must_not": [
                       {
                          "exists": {
                             "field": "crawl_date"
                          }
                       }
                    ]
                 }
              },
              {
                 "range": {
                    "crawl_date": {
                       "from": "now-100d"
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     },
     "aggs": {
        "group_by_domain": {
           "terms": {
              "field": "domain"
           }
        }
      }
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: That doesn't give me what I need. I want to pick 10 urls that haven't been crawled for a while (or crawled at all) and each of those 10 urls has to be from a unique domain so that when I crawl those 10 urls I am not overloading someone's server.

Comment: You have to change `from ` in crawl_date.